# My upload script wont upload for some reason

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image file but it doesn't seem to work with this code:

**upload.php**

```
<?php

$worked=1;
$file_up_size=$_FILES['img'][size];
if ($_FILES[img][size]>250000){
echo "Your file size is above 250KB please reduce it and re-upload it.<br>";
break;
$worked=0;
}

$img_name = $_FILES[img][name];
$img_dir = "uploads/$img_name";

if($worked == 1){

if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES[img][tmp_name], $img_dir)){
}
else {
    echo "WARNING: File upload failed!";
    break;
}

}
?>
```

**img_form.html**

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
upload: <input name="img" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please format your post correctly...

Comment: Possible error could be with your max_upload_size in the php.ini file. Please increase it and try uploading again.

Comment: Also check your http servers error log file. It will probably tell you what the issue is. Could for example be a permission issue.

Comment: How do I get the log file? What directory?

Comment: By default, `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: My max file upload is 2M is that 2 mb's or ?

Comment: Yes, thats 2mb, change that to 50M

Comment: I cant, my (free) vm doesn't let me edit the php.ini file any other ways that I can change it, through the command prompt or something

Comment: Nope I am using a free vps (with koding)

Comment: https://koding.com/Activity/how-to-edit-phpini-file

Comment: Try use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: Please ensure that uploads/ exists and is writable. Does you get any Output? You should consider enabling display_errors

Comment: so I write display_errors(); right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works on any normal website host, but my vps had some dogy settings in php.ini which I still dont know of but at least the script works!